# how to display JFrame in full screen display mode at a multi-monitor environment?

Tags: java, swing, awt, fullscreen, multiple-monitors

There is a JFrame, when it in a multi-monitor environment, how to display this JFrame in full screen display? For example, now the JFrame is displaying in monitor 1, when it is going to change to full screen display mode,it must be displayed in the monitor 1; if is displaying in monitor 2,when it is going  to change to  full screen display mode, it must be displayed in
the monitor 2.

Comment: The question is when it in monitor 1 or 2,then it changes to full-screen mode,the jframe will be displayed in monitor 1.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

For Single Screen

```
Toolkit tool = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
Dimension dim = tool.getScreenSize();
int screenWidth = dim.getWidth();
int screenHeight = dim.getHeight();
```

For Multiple Screen

```
GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
GraphicsDevice[] gs = ge.getScreenDevices();


// Get size of each screen

for (int i=0; i<gs.length; i++) {
    DisplayMode dm = gs[i].getDisplayMode();
    int screenWidth = dm.getWidth();
    int screenHeight = dm.getHeight();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your attention.But then how? Not focus on how to display in full-screen mode, but in the current monitor display it.

Comment: setSize(screenWidth,screenHeight);

Comment: The question is when it in monitor 1 or 2,then it changes to full-screen mode,the jframe will always be displayed in monitor 1.